# Individual CI vs Batched CI in Azure Pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

What is the difference between Individual CI and Batched CI in Azure Pipelines ?

How does it relate to the `batch` option of `trigger` in Azure Pipelines YAML ?

```
trigger:
  batch: 'true'
  branches:
    include:
     - main
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How does it relate to the batch option of trigger in Azure Pipelines YAML ?

As the document [Push trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#push-trigger) stated:

```
trigger:
  batch: boolean # batch changes if true; start a new build for every push if false (default)
```

**Explanation:**

Build batching will **take multiple pushes (branch updates) and build them all at once** in one batch instead of queuing each commit as a separate build which would extend the total time to build.   If you are building code in Azure Pipelines and often find yourself waiting for queued builds. You may find it useful to enable build batching.

So, we could understand the state in that document now `start a new build for every push if false (default)`. That means that if we set the value of this batch option to false, it will start **a new build for every push (commit)**.

This is equivalent to our **Batch changes while a build is in progress** option in Classic mode：

[image]

Comment: Found [this explanation](https://cloudskills.io/blog/ci-dotnet-core#:~:text=Batch%20changes%20while%20a%20build,as%20a%20separate%20pipeline%20run.) also useful: "Batch changes while a build is in progress - if you work on a large team where there are frequent pushes and/or PR completion pushes, you may end up queuing multiple builds while a build is still in progress. This checkbox will stop each of these pushes being queued as a separate pipeline run. It will queue one run of all the changes once the current build is complete."

Comment: @geekshift, Agree. Thanks for your sharing here. Have a nice day!

Comment: One build for multiple builds is nice. What happens when 1 of the commit fails the build ?

Comment: I think using the word "commit" in this answer may be confusing to some. Imagine the scenario where 50 new commits are merged into a branch at once. That would trigger 1 build, not 50 builds. (This is probably obvious to most people but I'd propose removing the 2 occurrences of the word "commit" just to avoid any potential confusion.) I think "pushes" or "branch updates" works well here.